# Provide a jump to "questions you just asked"

Tags: feature-request, questions, stack-exchange-button

Usually you can jump to questions you just asked using `inbox` from the StackExchange menu (provided you have gotten some interactions/answers)

But it would be helpful to provide a one-click jump to "Questions you just asked" in the SE box.

[image]

`hot questions` is great for something to browse, but I think a jump to questions I just asked (on any site) would be nice.

Comment: I would really like this feature for "recently answered" questions

Comment: Can't see why not, other than there being _too many_ options. fwiw I never use "hot questions", and `notifications` could be subsumed under `inbox`

Answer (score 3):

To the right of the Stack Exchange button, you'll find your user link.

[image]

When you click that, you get to see not only your recent questions but even more than that....

Comment: Only if you got reputation for that questions

Comment: Not sure what you mean, this works for everyone, you can sort them by "newest"...

Comment: @juergend: He said to click on the user link, not the arrow.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn: Oh I see. Indeed, the link in red on above picture.

Comment: No but, that's for the site you're on only, not SE-wide

Comment: That wasn't clear from your question.

Comment: The SE button is network-wide functionality.